# Phonegap : 9patch image malformed

Tags: android, cordova, nine-patch

I am trying to run a Phonegap application but some images in the resources directory are preventing it from starting. when i delete the images files from my project it works just fine.

Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/macbookpro/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt s -i ../platforms/android/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.9.png -o ../platforms/android/build/intermediates/res/debug/drawable-land-xhdpi-v4/screen.9.png

```
Output: ERROR: 9-patch image ../platforms/android/res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.9.png malformed.
       No marked region found along edge.
       Found along top edge.
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove all your splash.png files and clean your cordova project by using this command `./platforms/android/cordova/clean`
then copy the splash.9.png files in your res folders
then build the project, that worked for me.
You can make .9.png files with the help of this online [tool](http://draw9patch.com/#url=splash-ldpi.png&top[]=0&top[]=23&top[]=296&top[]=320&right[]=426&right[]=426&bottom[]=320&bottom[]=320&left[]=0&left[]=155&left[]=261&left[]=426)